# public void method in for loop; can't recieve loop variable

Tags: java, android, loops, void

Here's my **for** loop. **Problem:** I need to get a listener on an array of buttons and get the button depending on array number appending some text to a `textview` array with the same number.

Problem is, I can't get `int i` to the public void method. If I declare it my main class, the application just gets failed. When I'm changing the `i` value to some real integer, it works. so I figured out that the problem is - **onClick** method is receiving a `null` instead of `i`.

```
 for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
     btninput.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             converswindow.get(i).append(Html.fromHtml("<b>Вы:</b> "+msginput.get(i).getText()+"<br />"));
             msginput.get(i).setText("");
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work or not, but try:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    btninput.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            converswindow.get(j).append(Html.fromHtml("<b>Вы:</b> "+msginput.get(i).getText()+"<br />"));
            msginput.get(j).setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can use Android's View tag mechanism to add data to the button. Read about `View.setTag(...)` and `View.getTag(...)` for more information there.

Comment: Heh, didn't even thought about a such  solution. Looks very strange, but it's working.

Answer (score 1):

anonymous classes can't access local vars in their methods you need to make them instance vars of the objects (here I did it with `ind`)

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        btninput.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             int ind=i;//here keep a copy of the local var

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              converswindow.get(ind).append(Html.fromHtml("<b>Вы:</b> "+msginput.get(ind).getText()+"<br />"));
              msginput.get(ind).setText("");
            }
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
public void onClick(View v) {
              converswindow.get(btninput.indexOf(v)).append(Html.fromHtml("<b>Вы:</b> "+msginput.get(btninput.indexOf(v).getText()+"<br />"));
              msginput.get(btninput.indexOf(v)).setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create a custom `OnClickListener` and give it a constructor that receives an `int`:

```
public class CustomListener implements OnClickListener {
    int i;

    CustomListener(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        converswindow.get(j).append(Html.fromHtml("<b>Вы:</b>"+msginput.get(i).getText()+"<br />"));
        msginput.get(j).setText("");
    }

}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
btninput.get(i).setOnClickListener(new CustomListener(i));
```